# Redirecting specific request to a node in cluster using modjk

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-jk

I have created a cluster(load balancer) which consists of two node node1 and node2, now i want node2 to handle specific request like /context/heavyservice1, /context/vheavyservice and both node1 and node2 to handle /context/service (which is working fine) , my question is how can i configure modjk so that node 2 will handle some servcies.

Below is some part of my configuartion

```
worker.list= lbNode
worker.lbNode.type=lb


worker.node1.type=ajp13

worker.node1.port=8009

worker.node1.host=server1

worker.node2.type=ajp13

worker.node2.port=8009

worker.node2.host=server2

worker.lbNode.balance_workers=node1,node2
```

Comment: What are your existing JkMount  statements?

Comment: @jlumietu JKMount /context                             JKMount /context/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test this way:

```
worker.list=lbNode,node1,node2

worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=server1

worker.node2.type=ajp13
worker.node2.port=8009
worker.node2.host=server2

worker.lbNode.balance_workers=node1,node2
worker.lbNode.type=lb
```

Then you must set the mappings. You can set mappings to different nodes in the same virtual host (or in the default host, without creating any virtual host). Just use JKMount and JKUnMount to match your requirements

```
JKMount /context lbNode
JKMount /context/* lbNode
JKUnMount /context/heavyservice1 lbNode
JKUnMount /context/vheavyservice lbNode
JKMount /context/heavyservice1 node2
JKMount /context/vheavyservice node2
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can set additional VirtualHosts to route straight to a particular node.

eg :

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName node1.com
  JkMount /application node1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName node2.com
  JkMount /application node2
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Then I have to also add node1 and node2 to worker list as well?

Comment: Yes, Make sure the JBoss worker nodes are included in the worker list and not just the balance_workers, for example: worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1,node2 worker.list=loadbalancer,status,node1,node2